# Javascript / Node JS best way to create singleton object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I completed my home work and got perfect result. But i just want to check , is this the best way to create singleton instances or is their any other way:

I created a singleton object using the module pattern (closures) as, "app.js"

```
var singleton1 = require('./singletonUser1');
console.dir(singleton1.getlocalvariable());
singleton1.setlocalvariable(20);
console.dir(singleton1.getlocalvariable());

var singleton2 = require('./singletonUser2');
console.dir(singleton2.getlocalvariable());
singleton2.setlocalvariable(30);
console.dir(singleton.getlocalvariable());
```

Actual singleton object (singleton.js):

```
var singleton = (function () {
    var localvariable = 10;

    return {
        getlocalvariable: function () {
            console.dir('This is getInstance');
            return localvariable;
        },
        setlocalvariable: function (value) {
            console.dir('This is setlocalvariable');
            localvariable = value;
        },
    };
})();

module.exports = singleton;
```

Then Singleton object user 1 (singletonUser1.js):

```
var singletonUser1 = (function () {
    var singleton = require('./singleton');

    return {
        getlocalvariable: function () {
            console.dir('This is singletonUser1---getlocalvariable');
            return singleton.getlocalvariable();
        },
        setlocalvariable: function (value) {
            console.dir('This is singletonUser1---setlocalvariable');
            singleton.setlocalvariable(value);
        },
    };
})();

module.exports = singletonUser1;
```

Singleton Object User 2 (singletonUser2.js)

```
var singletonUser2 = (function () {
    var singleton = require('./singleton');

    return {
        getlocalvariable: function () {
            console.dir('This is singletonUser2222---getlocalvariable');
            return singleton.getlocalvariable();
        },
        setlocalvariable: function (value) {
            console.dir('This is singletonUser22222---setlocalvariable');
            singleton.setlocalvariable(value);
        },
    };
})();
module.exports = singletonUser2;
```

Please consider that, Single User 1 and User 2, is for a purpose according to my project, the above is just an prototype to the real world problem.

My question is, I am sure this is creating a single instance of the class (As i checked using the app.js above). But is this the best way?

Comment: You may have more luck posting this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, since you're not asking to solve a problem.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda yes you are right i am not asking to solve the problem, i will try to post code review forum. But, my request is to know, is their a better approach then using the closures and also want to know some debugging techniques like, how to verify how many instances of particular objects are their at runtime.

Comment: No problem in asking that, it's just that CodeReview is there for that specific reason. You might get answers here, but you will have more luck and better ones over there!

Comment: This would not be good for Code Review as it is not real, implemented code, but rather is hypothetical. This would get closed on CR for that reason.

Comment: @Phrancis Ah, good point. I retract my statement then.

Comment: @Phrancis If it works, I would say that it's not hypothetical; but that it's not in any production system.

Comment: @user3278897 The problem with your implementation is that you are calling two modules that, for the most part, look the same.  Is your homework asking you to have two separate files?  I'm guessing not.  The special thing about singletons/closures (what I'm guessing your professor is trying to teach) is that you can have two instances built from the same class, which hold different values and maintain their state throughout the program.  However, this is not what you are doing above.  Above, you're creating two instances from two *different* classes, which happen to be defined almost the same.

Comment: @vol7ron pordon me, if i made you feel like i am doing this for assignment. Acttually i am doing it for a project, as mentioned in the question (..."User 1 and 2 are just an prototype to the real world problem" ), I am getting instances of the singleton class in two or many different classes. It is creating only one instance, as per the log outputs in the app.js. But, i didnot understood your comment last sentence, " Above, you're creating two instances from two different classes...", as i said in the question it is creating only one instance

Comment: @user3278897 are you using two different files (modules) to create *singletonUser1* and *singletonUser2*?  The constructors (classes) of each, look very much the same, but that's missing the point.  You should be creating two singletons from the same class, not from two separate classes.

Comment: @vol7ron I am sorry you are confusing me. As simple, all i want is, access the singleton class / instance from two different modules.In the question I mentioned, tested it and it is creating only one instance. you can just copy/paste and test the code.

Comment: @vol7ron I am sorry :) please let me know, if you want me to add some more explanation. I will add it.

Comment: @user3278897 Your code is not clearly defined.  Usually when you call a *require* it's calling a specific file.  I assume you have two files, one called *singletonUser1* and one called *singletonUser2*. -- Is that correct?  If you cannot answer that question, I suggest you copy and paste your own code into something more presentable, like http://jsapp.us/

Comment: @user3278897 if that is correct (that you have two files), they should be compressed into 1.  The point of classes is that you can create many instances from them.  For instance, if you have a *Dog* class, you can say `var dog1=new Dog(), dog2=new Dog();` -- notice you don't say `dog1=new Dog1(), dog2=new Dog2()` (this is what you're doing in your code - you have two different classes, that look almost the same except for the console message).  You should be defining a class in such a way that it can be reused and you should reuse it.

Comment: @jsapp Yes you are correct, in my app.js file above, it clearly takes from two different files, singletonUser1 and singletonUser2. I will add some more extra words to my question now.

Comment: @vol7ron please didnot look at singletonUser1.js and singletonUser2.js, as i said it is just prototype. For our discussion sake, i am saying, in real world, singleton class is a "Analysis module / class / object" and the singletonUser1.js is a Business and singletonUser2.js is a Stock Market which uses the "Analysis -- singleton" and these two Business and Stock Market Modules are instantiated in the app.js

Comment: If they are subclasses, which will differentiate, then that's fine. However, your definition and naming makes it appear as though singleUser1 and singleUser2 will have the same format, which is what sparked this conversation.

Comment: @vol7ron it is ok vol7ron :) i can understand. But i modified the question with clear lables now, please check it.

Comment: Is it more clear now why we don't accept hypothetical/example code on Code Review? ;-)  But please, once you have this structure/code implemented and working as designed, do bring it over to CR, we can certainly help you make it even better!

Comment: @Phrancis My headsOff, i accept and i will post it on the code review. It is actually for a open source project which i started. I will definitely require all you experts advice and support.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var Singleton = (function(){
  function Singleton(){
    this.localVariable = 5;
  }

  // Object can have instance methods as usually.
  Singleton.prototype.getLocalVariable = function() {
    return this.localVariable;
  };

  var instance;

  return function() {
    if (!instance) {
      instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return instance;
  };
})();


var instance1 = new Singleton();
var instance2 = new Singleton();

console.log(instance1 === instance2); // true

console.log(instance1.localVariable, instance2.localVariable); // 5 5

instance1.localVariable = 20;
console.log(instance1.localVariable, instance2.localVariable); // 20 20

console.log(instance1.getLocalVariable()); // 20
```

Comment: This is probably closer to what the homework assignment is after

Answer (score 1):

this is my configurable singleton for a service

```js
function AdService(name) {
    console.log('new instance created');
    this.name = name || 'defaultName';
    this.greet = function () {
        console.log('hi ' + this.name);
    }
};

function Singleton() {
    this.instance = null;
    this.getInstance = function getInstance(name) {
        if (!this.instance)
            this.instance = new AdService(name);

        return this.instance;
    }
}

var singleton = new Singleton();

module.exports = function (name) {
    return singleton.getInstance(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find singleton class in JavaScript bit wobbly, in java it is quite clear, i.e whenever you create an object of a class, you get the same object, but in JS, (at least IMO) there is no true class to begin with.( nope, ES6 classes don't count, answer this, can you have private attributes in that?)

You code just does a closure,  it might well have been the below code and made no difference:

```
var localvariable = 10;

function getlocalvariable() {
    console.dir('This is getInstance');
    return localvariable;
};
function setlocalvariable(value) {
    console.dir('This is setlocalvariable');
    localvariable = value;
};
module.exports = {
  getlocalvariable: getlocalvariable,
  setlocalvariable: setlocalvariable
};
```

that said, end of day, Singleton is just a pattern, how we implement depends on us, nothing particularly wrong with the way you did.

**Edit:** A singleton implementation by someone who knows JS better than me (taken from [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript))

```
var mySingleton = (function () {

  // Instance stores a reference to the Singleton
  var instance;

  function init() {

    // Singleton

    // Private methods and variables
    function privateMethod(){
        console.log( "I am private" );
    }

    var privateVariable = "Im also private";

    var privateRandomNumber = Math.random();

    return {

      // Public methods and variables
      publicMethod: function () {
        console.log( "The public can see me!" );
      },

      publicProperty: "I am also public",

      getRandomNumber: function() {
        return privateRandomNumber;
      }

    };

  };

  return {

    // Get the Singleton instance if one exists
    // or create one if it doesn't
    getInstance: function () {

      if ( !instance ) {
        instance = init();
      }

      return instance;
    }

  };

})();

var myBadSingleton = (function () {

  // Instance stores a reference to the Singleton
  var instance;

  function init() {

    // Singleton

    var privateRandomNumber = Math.random();

    return {

      getRandomNumber: function() {
        return privateRandomNumber;
      }

    };

  };

  return {

    // Always create a new Singleton instance
    getInstance: function () {

      instance = init();

      return instance;
    }

  };

})();


// Usage:

var singleA = mySingleton.getInstance();
var singleB = mySingleton.getInstance();
console.log( singleA.getRandomNumber() === singleB.getRandomNumber() ); // true

var badSingleA = myBadSingleton.getInstance();
var badSingleB = myBadSingleton.getInstance();
console.log( badSingleA.getRandomNumber() !== badSingleB.getRandomNumber() ); // true

// Note: as we are working with random numbers, there is a
// mathematical possibility both numbers will be the same,
// however unlikely. The above example should otherwise still
// be valid.
```

Comment: You can have private attributes (variables) in JavaScript, it's just not the syntax that you're familiar with: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html  - and this is old.  But also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties

Comment: @vol7ron, I was talking about private attributes in ES6 classes :)

Comment: There's no keyword, as you'd expect in Java or C, but there is still that method described above, which has the same affect (variables hidden behind closures).  There are other proposals to improve the ECMAScript 6 syntax, but like you said, none currently have an easy implementation of privatized attributes/methods -- certainly nothing that is easily readable.

Comment: @vol7ron nope, I am saying that there is no way to write pure ES6 class with private attributes...

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something, but you can create closures inside the constructor definition

Comment: yep and how exactly are you going to access the variables inside constructor closure in other methods of the class?

Comment: I don't understand how to answer your question.  I would say *easily*.  There are different examples online, many use WeakMaps.  Here's one: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3ezig4/using_es6_symbols_to_create_private_methods_and/ctkjcor  But I concur, privatization is problematic and needs more emphasis.